# display child data in parent show page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a project. I need your help. I have a parent table and a child table. Child table has the parent id. parent has many children and children belongs to parent. What I want is I want to display the child table data in the parent show.html.erb. Below is the show.html.erb file from parent folder

```
<p><strong>Primary Parent or Guardian in the home<br /></strong></p>
<p>First Name: <%= @parent.parent_1_firstname %></p>
<p>Last name:<%= @parent.parent_1_lastname %></p>
<hr>

<p><strong>Your Children<br /></strong></p>

<p>First Name: __________________</p>
```

what code should be written in dash area so that it shows the child first name from children table in the parent show.html.erb file. please help I am new to rails

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the parent's children:

```
<p><strong>Your Children<br /></strong></p>

<% @parent.children.each do |child| %>
  <p>First Name: <%= child.firstname %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That'll create an N+1 query. Consider using `includes`. See [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for more information.